# Swift числа с точкой

Tags: swift

В playground получаю такой вывод:

```
let a = 0.3
let b = 0.2
let c = 0.00001
    
print(a + b) // 0.5
print(a - b) // 0.10000001
print(c)     // 1e-05
```

Как избавиться от погрешности и получить привычный для калькулятора вывод?

```
print(a + b) // 0.5
print(a - b) // 0.1
print(c)     // 0.00001
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `Double` в данном случае попробуйте использовать `Decimal`, так как `Double` не обеспечивает точного представления числа, подробнее ответ дан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42782140/3004003).

```
let a = "0.3"
let b = "0.2"
let c = "0.00001"
        
print(Decimal(string: a)! + Decimal(string: b)!) // 0.5
print(Decimal(string: a)! - Decimal(string: b)!) // 0.1
print(Decimal(string: c)!)     // 0.00001
```